# Grafana with prometheus data source wrong values

Tags: time-series, grafana, prometheus

I am using grafana to display metrics based on prometheus data source. When using single stat panel with delta configuration I am getting wrong values. The values on prometheus are stored correctly, it looks something wrong in grafana when query with date filter, it show a lot of non sense results. Has something similar happened to someone?

Comment: Did you determine what was wrong in your setup?